# Using `group_by_rolling` to turn long sequence data into many shorter sequences? Also with a group column

Tags: dataframe, python-polars

I have a large timeseries dataset which I would like to decimate into shorter sequences, in reparation for using it with an LSTM model. I just cannot quite figure out the semantics of it.

Here's a toy example, that I think shows what I am trying to do:

```
df_ex = pl.DataFrame({
    "person": ["Alice",]*5 + ["Bob",]*5 + ["Cap"]*5,
    "x1" : np.array( [1,2,3,4,5]*3 ),
    "x2" : np.sin( [10,20,30,40,50]*3 ),
})
df_ex

shape: (15, 3)
┌────────┬─────┬───────────┐
│ person ┆ x1  ┆ x2        │
│ ---    ┆ --- ┆ ---       │
│ str    ┆ i64 ┆ f64       │
╞════════╪═════╪═══════════╡
│ Alice  ┆ 1   ┆ -0.544021 │
│ Alice  ┆ 2   ┆ 0.912945  │
│ Alice  ┆ 3   ┆ -0.988032 │
│ Alice  ┆ 4   ┆ 0.745113  │
│ …      ┆ …   ┆ …         │
│ Cap    ┆ 2   ┆ 0.912945  │
│ Cap    ┆ 3   ┆ -0.988032 │
│ Cap    ┆ 4   ┆ 0.745113  │
│ Cap    ┆ 5   ┆ -0.262375 │
└────────┴─────┴───────────┘
```

then turning it into sequences:

```
df_lists = (df_ex
            .with_columns( pl.ones(pl.count(), dtype=pl.Int32).cumsum().over('person').alias('enum') )
            .group_by_rolling(by='person', index_column='enum', period='3i')
            .agg( pl.col(['x1','x2'])  )
            .filter( pl.col('x1').list.lengths() >=3 )
            )
df_lists

shape: (9, 4)
┌────────┬──────┬───────────┬──────────────────────────────────┐
│ person ┆ enum ┆ x1        ┆ x2                               │
│ ---    ┆ ---  ┆ ---       ┆ ---                              │
│ str    ┆ i32  ┆ list[i64] ┆ list[f64]                        │
╞════════╪══════╪═══════════╪══════════════════════════════════╡
│ Alice  ┆ 3    ┆ [1, 2, 3] ┆ [-0.544021, 0.912945, -0.988032] │
│ Alice  ┆ 4    ┆ [2, 3, 4] ┆ [0.912945, -0.988032, 0.745113]  │
│ Alice  ┆ 5    ┆ [3, 4, 5] ┆ [-0.988032, 0.745113, -0.262375] │
│ Bob    ┆ 3    ┆ [1, 2, 3] ┆ [-0.544021, 0.912945, -0.988032] │
│ Bob    ┆ 4    ┆ [2, 3, 4] ┆ [0.912945, -0.988032, 0.745113]  │
│ Bob    ┆ 5    ┆ [3, 4, 5] ┆ [-0.988032, 0.745113, -0.262375] │
│ Cap    ┆ 3    ┆ [1, 2, 3] ┆ [-0.544021, 0.912945, -0.988032] │
│ Cap    ┆ 4    ┆ [2, 3, 4] ┆ [0.912945, -0.988032, 0.745113]  │
│ Cap    ┆ 5    ┆ [3, 4, 5] ┆ [-0.988032, 0.745113, -0.262375] │
└────────┴──────┴───────────┴──────────────────────────────────┘
```

So now, df_lists has shape `(9,4)`.

As you can see, there's a group for `"person"`, here, which needs to be maintained.

I ultimately want to end up with a numpy array with shape `(3,3,3,2)`,
where:
dim 0 : person (ordinally - I will need to track this)
dim 1 : sequence #
dim 2 : along the sequence
dim 3 : features at each sequence point

Alternately, maybe dropping dim 0 in favor of a dictionary would be smarter.
But I am not even sure how to start collapsing dimensions here, so either outcome would be fine.

My questions are:

1. Is there a straightforward way to get that numpy array out? Or maybe something close, that will require swapaxes to get there.
2. The way of accomplishing the `group_by_dynamic` seems fairly roundabout, so please let me know if I've done something silly.

---

### EDIT:

OK, following the help from @jqurious , and to clarify the problem, let's add some more.
Yes, the code below gives a dictionary, just so I can keep mental track of this as I implement ... and actually just using a `dict` might be fine, in the long run, as I can still wrap a custom torch `DataLoader` around that, which iterates of sequences of sequences from one person at a time. (just how the RL game has to work)
The initial attraction to a 4d list was because I thought I could do it all via polars grammar, without any outer loop.

Notably, this now doesn't even use `group_by_rolling`.

Below is some code that does seem to accomplish what I want.
Note that I do have to do the `.swapaxes(1,0).swapaxes(2,1)` swizzle at the end.

```
import collections
from itertools import islice

def sliding_window(iterable, n):
    # sliding_window('ABCDEFG', 4) --> ABCD BCDE CDEF DEFG
    it = iter(iterable)
    window = collections.deque(islice(it, n-1), maxlen=n)
    for x in it:
        window.append(x)
        yield tuple(window)

all_seqs = {}
pids = df_ex['person'].unique()
for pid in pids:
    df = df_ex.filter( pl.col('person') == pid )

    seqs = np.array(
        [
            list( sliding_window( df_ex['x1'], 3 ) ),
            list( sliding_window( df_ex['x2'], 3 ) ),
        ]
    )
    print(f"{pid}: {seqs.shape}")
    if seqs.shape[1] == 0:
        continue

    seqs = seqs.swapaxes(1,0).swapaxes(2,1)
    all_seqs[pid] = seqs
```

then:
`all_seqs['Bob'].shape == (3, 3, 2)`
and `all_seqs['Bob']` is:

```
array([[[ 1.        , -0.54402111],
        [ 2.        ,  0.91294525],
        [ 3.        , -0.98803162]],

       [[ 2.        ,  0.91294525],
        [ 3.        , -0.98803162],
        [ 4.        ,  0.74511316]],

       [[ 3.        , -0.98803162],
        [ 4.        ,  0.74511316],
        [ 5.        , -0.26237485]]])
```

In the "ideal" case, it would be a df such that:
`df[0,:,:,:] --> "Bob"`
`df[1,:,:,:] --> "Alice"`
`df[2,:,:,:] --> "Cap"`

Comment: Could you perhaps show the actual numpy array you expect from this example? It's a little difficult (for me, at least) to make out from the description.

Comment: @jqurious I think they mean that dim0 is person (int encoded I guess), dim1 is enum, dim2 is x1, and then dim3 is x2 except that implies a shape of (3,3,3,3) not (3,3,3,2) so I guess I'm stumped.

Comment: @jqurious Sure. Yes, this is made complicated by the `"person"` groups. But, I will ultimately have to deal with that in my base dataset, unless I figure out some operation that I can then do in a loop over `.filter`'d subsets.  
  
I will update the question rn with an example using `sliding_window` that gives me what I want and may be a fine overall solution. What I REALLY could not come to terms with was: What do I do with a polars list type?

Comment: Apologies, I wasn't suggesting to use `itertools` - I was just asking if anybody else thought a "dedicated function"  feature request (using `sliding_window` as an existing example) for Polars was worth considering. (compared to the somewhat awkward `.group_by_rolling()` + `.filter()` that is currently needed)

Comment: @jqurious Oh, well, it WAS a good way of accomplishing what I need! I was just trying to do it without a loop-and-accumulate approach.

Comment: Perhaps I was overthinking things. If you start with a regular `.group_by` instead, it's just a matter of using `.slice()` - I've added an example as a separate answer. (The original answer can probably be deleted now as it no longer seems relevant/useful.)

Answer (score 0):

Just addressing point #2 until further clarification of the desired output:

> The way of accomplishing the `group_by_rolling` seems fairly roundabout

The current approach can be simplified a small bit:

- [`.int_range()`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.int_range.html) for the enumeration
- if you are extracting a column "as-is", you can refer to it directly without `pl.col()`

```py
(df.with_columns( pl.int_range(0, pl.count()).over('person').alias('enum') )
   .group_by_rolling(by='person', index_column='enum', period='3i')
   .agg( 'x1','x2' )
   .filter( pl.col('x1').list.len() >=3 )
)
```

```
shape: (9, 4)
┌────────┬──────┬───────────┬──────────────────────────────────┐
│ person ┆ enum ┆ x1        ┆ x2                               │
│ ---    ┆ ---  ┆ ---       ┆ ---                              │
│ str    ┆ i64  ┆ list[i64] ┆ list[f64]                        │
╞════════╪══════╪═══════════╪══════════════════════════════════╡
│ Alice  ┆ 2    ┆ [1, 2, 3] ┆ [-0.544021, 0.912945, -0.988032] │
│ Alice  ┆ 3    ┆ [2, 3, 4] ┆ [0.912945, -0.988032, 0.745113]  │
│ Alice  ┆ 4    ┆ [3, 4, 5] ┆ [-0.988032, 0.745113, -0.262375] │
│ Bob    ┆ 2    ┆ [1, 2, 3] ┆ [-0.544021, 0.912945, -0.988032] │
│ Bob    ┆ 3    ┆ [2, 3, 4] ┆ [0.912945, -0.988032, 0.745113]  │
│ Bob    ┆ 4    ┆ [3, 4, 5] ┆ [-0.988032, 0.745113, -0.262375] │
│ Cap    ┆ 2    ┆ [1, 2, 3] ┆ [-0.544021, 0.912945, -0.988032] │
│ Cap    ┆ 3    ┆ [2, 3, 4] ┆ [0.912945, -0.988032, 0.745113]  │
│ Cap    ┆ 4    ┆ [3, 4, 5] ┆ [-0.988032, 0.745113, -0.262375] │
└────────┴──────┴───────────┴──────────────────────────────────┘
```

- DeprecationWarning: `lengths` is deprecated. It has been renamed to `len`. <sup>https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/11577</sup>

It is also possible to pass an expression directly to `index_column`

```py
(
   df.group_by_rolling(
      by = "person",
      index_column = pl.int_range(0, pl.count()).over("person").alias("enum"),
      period = "3i"
   )
   .agg("x1", "x2")
   .filter(pl.col("x1").list.len() >= 3)
)
```

Perhaps there is room for a feature/enhancement request to simplify this particular task in Polars?

[itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) calls this `.sliding_window()` in its recipe examples, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a regular `.group_by()` and "manual slicing"
with [`.slice()`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.slice.html#polars.Expr.slice) is a simpler approach.

```py
all_seqs = (
   df.group_by("person")
     .agg(
        pl.concat_list(pl.exclude("person").slice(n, 3)).alias(f"{n}")
        for n in range(3)
     )
)
```

```
shape: (3, 4)
┌────────┬───────────────────────────────────┬───────────────────────────────────┬───────────────────────────────────┐
│ person ┆ 0                                 ┆ 1                                 ┆ 2                                 │
│ ---    ┆ ---                               ┆ ---                               ┆ ---                               │
│ str    ┆ list[list[f64]]                   ┆ list[list[f64]]                   ┆ list[list[f64]]                   │
╞════════╪═══════════════════════════════════╪═══════════════════════════════════╪═══════════════════════════════════╡
│ Alice  ┆ [[1.0, -0.544021], [2.0, 0.91294… ┆ [[2.0, 0.912945], [3.0, -0.98803… ┆ [[3.0, -0.988032], [4.0, 0.74511… │
│ Cap    ┆ [[1.0, -0.544021], [2.0, 0.91294… ┆ [[2.0, 0.912945], [3.0, -0.98803… ┆ [[3.0, -0.988032], [4.0, 0.74511… │
│ Bob    ┆ [[1.0, -0.544021], [2.0, 0.91294… ┆ [[2.0, 0.912945], [3.0, -0.98803… ┆ [[3.0, -0.988032], [4.0, 0.74511… │
└────────┴───────────────────────────────────┴───────────────────────────────────┴───────────────────────────────────┘
```

As for unpacking into a numpy array, perhaps [`.rows_by_key()`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.rows_by_key.html#polars.DataFrame.rows_by_key) may help here:

```py
all_seqs = { k: np.array(v[0]) for k, v in all_seqs.rows_by_key("person").items() }
```

```py
all_seqs["Bob"]
```

```py
array([[[ 1.        , -0.54402111],
        [ 2.        ,  0.91294525],
        [ 3.        , -0.98803162]],

       [[ 2.        ,  0.91294525],
        [ 3.        , -0.98803162],
        [ 4.        ,  0.74511316]],

       [[ 3.        , -0.98803162],
        [ 4.        ,  0.74511316],
        [ 5.        , -0.26237485]]])
```